# Display image from another node

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I have a front page where i need to display a selected news item from the news section of the site, including an image.

I started off by trying to do a simple modification of the standard image, and promptly got nowhere.

I have verified that the images work when shown via currentpage directly on the node, but the following does not work:

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="mediaID" select="$currentPage/forsidenyhed/billede" />
  <xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/forsidenyhed" />
    <xsl:if test="string($mediaID) != ''">
      <xsl:variable name="media" select="umbraco.library:GetMedia($currentPage/forsidenyhed/billede, false)" />
          <xsl:if test="string($media) != ''">
            <div class="forsidebillede">
              <img src="{$media/umbracoFile}" alt="{$media/altText}" />
            </div>
          </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The value-of outputs the correct node-id for the node containing the image i am looking for.

Edit: For anybody having problems with the same exact situation (umbraco cms) i recomend using a Razor macro instead of XSLT.

Comment: Please post a more complete snippet of your stylesheet - together with your XML input.

Comment: i can't see why you need to verify things i know work.

Comment: Then (i.e if you are not willing to disclose crucial information) you should not expect anyone to help you.

Comment: look im sorry but these are not usualy relevant things in umbraco.
i have never had to export my node structure so i don't actually know how.
as for my code i, i dont see why you need my libraries but sure, ill add em

Comment: ugh, it won't let me input the library referances to my code

Comment: I understand. But there are fewer people here that are familiar with umbraco than with XSLT. So, if you show a complete stylesheet and XML input you have better chances that XSLT "generalists" can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Following code provides the functionality i was looking for:

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@{
  dynamic settingsNode = Model.AncestorOrSelf();
  dynamic searchPageNode = new DynamicNode(settingsNode.forsidenyhed);
  dynamic mediaItem = new DynamicMedia(@searchPageNode.billede);
  }
<img src="@mediaItem.umbracoFile">
```